# Python, problem with parsing json with json.loads()

Tags: python, json

I have a problem with a script I just did on my raspberry. (I have an arduino which sends me data wirelessly with an HC12 module on the raspberry to send to a server)

I can read the data, prepare it and send it to the server as I want, but when I want to retrieve the data a **2nd time** (2nd time the arduino sends data) I **get this error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tip_ws.py", line 33, in <module>
    data_j = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 156 (char 155)
```

Can you help me? Thank you very much already in advance!

This is what my arduino send to the raspberry :

```
[{"stationMeteo":1,"pression":9055,"temperature":26.4,"humidite":62,"luminosite":85,"uv":3,"pluie":0,"qualiteAir":60,"vent":5.3}]
```

Here is the code for my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from time import sleep
import serial
import requests
import json
import time

url='myURL'

data = ""
letter_last=""

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)    #Open port with baud rate
while True:
    data += ser.read()
    #received_data = ser.read()              #read serial port
    #sleep(0.03)
    #data_left = ser.inWaiting()             #check for remaining byte
    #received_data += ser.read(data_left)
    #received_data = received_data.strip()


    #Récupération du dernier caractère
    letter_last = data[-1]

    #Si dernier caractère est égal à "]" le message est terminé !
    if letter_last == "]":
        #Récupération du contenu sans les accolades "[" et "]"
        data = data[1:-1]
        #Decodage des données en JSON
        data_j = json.loads(data)

        #Récupération des données
        password = "mypassword"
        stationmeteo = data_j.get('stationMeteo')
        pression = data_j.get('pression')
        temperature = data_j.get('temperature')
        humidite = data_j.get('humidite')
        luminosite = data_j.get('luminosite')
        uv = data_j.get('uv')
        pluie = data_j.get('pluie')
        qualiteAir = data_j.get('qualiteAir')
        vent = data_j.get('vent')

#Préparation de l'objet JSON à envoyer dans la requête HTTP au serveur
        content = {
                'password' : password,
                'stationMeteo' : stationmeteo,
                'pression' : pression,
                'temperature' : temperature,
                'humidite' : humidite,
                'luminosite' : luminosite,
                'uv' : uv,
                'pluie' : pluie,
                'qualiteAir' : qualiteAir,
                'vent' : vent
        }

        #Création de la requête HTTP avec l'url et l'objet JSON
        response = requests.post(url, content)

        #Affichage des informations
        print ('AJOUT DONNEES - ' + time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") + '\n')
        print (content)
        print ('\n')
        print (response.json().get('response'))
        print ('---------------------------------')

        #Réinitialisation des données
        data = ""
        letter_last = ""
        content = ""
        data_j = ""
```

Comment: Your error complains about character 156, but your JSON has only 130 characters.

Comment: Why do you manually remove the leading/trailing ``[``/``]``? Are you sure there is exactly one list of one object in the input? The error message suggests you have incomplete data, such as a JSON list or object without a closing ``]``/``}``.